# Тотчас(,) когда

Tags: запятые

Можете сказать, как правильно?

1. И она видит: Он бреет бороду, годами ращённую на еге щёчке, **тотчас, когда** в его комнатушку-с она заходит – Анна.
2. И она видит: Он бреет бороду, годами ращённую на еге щёчке, **тотчас когда** в его комнатушку-с она заходит – Анна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем **второй вариант.**

*И она видит: Он бреет бороду, годами ращённую на еге щёчке, **тотчас когда** в его комнатушку-с она заходит – Анна.*

Или: И она видит: Он **тотчас** бреет бороду, годами ращённую на еге щёчке, **когда** в его комнатушку-с она заходит – Анна.

**Пояснение**

**Смысл такой**. Бороду он бреет редко, но начинает ее брить сразу же, когда заходит она.

**[По правилу Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)** к союзу ***КОГДА*** могут относиться наречия и частицы (пункт 5 и 6).

**ТОТЧАС,** нареч. Сейчас же, сразу. Т. вернулся. Т. исчез в темноте. Т. же ушёл прочь. Почти т. началась гроза. Уехал т. после обеда.

Comment: Так пояснений не будет, почему без запятой в **тотчас, когда**?

Comment: Я добавила правило Розенталя.

Comment: В нацкорпусе заговор непослушания — один на сотню — отсутствие случаев, где бы не было запятой меж **сразу/сейчас** и **тотчас**. Как и здесь в ответе (*сразу же, когда заходит*).

Comment: А вы дайте свой ответ, какой вариант вы считаете правильным. Интересно ведь! Здесь нужно выразить нужный смысл, а стилистика предложения не совсем обычная. Я сначала этот смысл подбирала, а потом выбирала форму.

Comment: Стилистику ув. автора стараюсь не видеть, и пока она такова, ответ врядли будет.

Comment: Творческая мастерская, поиск новых форм...  Нельзя же писать точно так, как раньше. Свежесть образов и слов утрачивается со временем: мы начинаем воспринимать текст как простую информацию, не чувствуем художественного пространства.  Вот я в ответе записала текст по смыслу, скучно и неинтересно. А как бы вы записали это предложение, чтобы оно звучало художественно?

Comment: Устаканил бы времена глаголов, чтобы они дружили, а не бодались, убрал бы нелепые дома*ращённые* слова.